# Save an image to outside the directory in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to save an image to server.Server directory structure is as follows

```
httpdocs-
    Folder-
         Page.aspx
```

and

```
httpdocs-
    Images-
          Subimages
```

The Folder and Images are under the httpdocs. I need to save the image to subimages folder from pages.aspx. Saving image code is on pages.aspx.

I tried 
`string CroppedImagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Subimages"+file)`
But not get the exact result

Comment: What have you tried and in what way did that attempt not succeed?  Show the actual code and indicate the results.

Comment: string CroppedImagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Subimages"+file)

Answer (score 0):

Unless `file` contains a leading `/` character, that's going to end up saving as something like:

```
~/Images/Subimagesfilename.ext
```

[Use `Path.Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to build a path name.  Something like this:

```
var CroppedImagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Subimages"), file);
```

Comment: No way i get the path as \\httpdocs\\Folder\\Images\\Subimages\\file i need \\httpdocs\\Images\\Subimages\\file

Comment: @vaava: Then clearly `Server.MapPath("~")` evaluates to `\\httpdocs\`.  If you want to save outside of the root path of the ASP.NET application then you can't use the `~` character, since that maps to the root of the application.  You can try something like: `~/../Folder/Images/Subimages` to try to move up one directory before looking for the `Folder` directory.  In general I'd recommend using an absolute path as a Web.config app settings value, so you can easily change it when needed.

Comment: I used     ~/../Folder/Images/Subimages     then i get the error "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory"

Comment: @vaava: Then you probably don't want to use `Server.MapPath()` in this case.  Just use an absolute path (such as `C:\httpdocs\Folder\`) instead.  You can still use tools like `Path.Combine()` to dynamically build it.  Then at that point I'd recommend tracking the path itself in a `Web.config` setting.

Answer (score 0):

try this
string CroppedImagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Subimages/"+file)
 / after Subimages